# does anybody know why UPNP GetSecurityKeys option gives me null wpa password?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, upnp, wpa2-psk

[image]
the [WLANConfiguration.xml](https://pastebin.com/y3i8DyfR)

the part where GetSecurityKeys is mentioned

```
<action>
<name>GetSecurityKeys</name>
<argumentList>
<argument>
<name>NewWEPKey0</name>
<direction>out</direction>
<relatedStateVariable>WEPKey</relatedStateVariable>
</argument>
<argument>
<name>NewWEPKey1</name>
<direction>out</direction>
<relatedStateVariable>WEPKey</relatedStateVariable>
</argument>
<argument>
<name>NewWEPKey2</name>
<direction>out</direction>
<relatedStateVariable>WEPKey</relatedStateVariable>
</argument>
<argument>
<name>NewWEPKey3</name>
<direction>out</direction>
<relatedStateVariable>WEPKey</relatedStateVariable>
</argument>
<argument>
<name>NewPreSharedKey</name>
<direction>out</direction>
<relatedStateVariable>PreSharedKey</relatedStateVariable>
</argument>
<argument>
<name>NewKeyPassphrase</name>
<direction>out</direction>
<relatedStateVariable>KeyPassphrase</relatedStateVariable>
</argument>
</argumentList>
```

i tried googling and the only thing i found was a pdf file called [UPnP-gw-WLANConfiguration-v1-Service.pdf](http://upnp.org/specs/gw/UPnP-gw-WLANConfiguration-v1-Service.pdf) the only null word i found in it is this and it have nothing to do with my problem !
[image]

i don't even have that `NewPreSharedKeyIndex` that is mentioned there in my wlan xml file

Comment: @Ramhound sure i do and i am not using it i am using wpa2 and i don't know why the upnp doesn't show its pass but shows wep !

Comment: @Ramhound "does anybody know why UPNP GetSecurityKeys option gives me null wpa password?"

it should show wpa pass in the screenshot too ... that's my question!

Answer (score 0):

It's an intended security mechanism

As critical info like the WIFI password shouldn't be Grabbable thro some insecure service like UPNP